# YOLO : Either overfits or underfits, increase batch or increase sample image pool?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, yolo

I'm trying to train my yolo model to identify fire extinguishers and to label it as "Fire Safety". Currently is either I get a overfit or underfit images(see below).

My sample images size with annotations is around ~1500

yolo-new.cfg config of width=608 and height=608

And I have trained using the following command:

> python flow --model cfg/yolo-new.cfg --labels one_label.txt  --train
>   --trainer adam --dataset "C://Users//G//Desktop//Development//ML//YOLO//BBox-Label-Tool//Images//002"
>   --annotation "C://Users//G//Desktop//Development//ML//YOLO//BBox-Label-Tool//AnnotationsXML//002"
>   --batch 4 --gpu 0.8

So after 13000 steps:
[image]

So I went to validate my results and this is what I get(Checkpoint 13000):
[image]

So perhaps I thought this might be a case of severe overfitting, thus I iterate through the checkpoints to see which has the closest fit.

This is what I get using checkpoint 6500
[image]

This is what I get using checkpoint 6000

[image]

This is what I get using checkpoint 5500
[image]

So, as you can see checkpoint 6000 is the best possible result in my case but it isn't good enough. How do I improve on this? Increase batch size ?(My GPU 1070Ti cant handle. Cuda out of memory occurs) Any Ideas to solve this?

Comment: For single class object detection what are all the config parameters have you changed from default YOLO config parameters?

Comment: @flamelite region to 1 and last convolutional filter to 30. full pastebin link:https://pastebin.com/0JH0fjsT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Yolov3 to train my imageset solved my issue. https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet

One thing to note is not to leave any blanks during annotation, perhaps this might be one of the reasons why the detection did not work as planned.